# Qt; QWidget removal and deletion. setParent(NULL) necessary?

Tags: c++, qt, parent-child, qwidget, delete-operator

I've been reading up on the ownership of Qwidgets and deleting them.
eg: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html

This says "You can also delete child objects yourself, and they will remove themselves from their parents"

However a lot of examples I have seen set the parent to null before deleting it.
eg:

```
if (widget != NULL)
{
    layout->removeWidget(widget); 
    widget->setParent(NULL);
    delete widget;
}
```

Is there any need for the `setParent(NULL);` ?

Leading on from this, is there any reason why I cannot just do a

```
delete layout->itemAt(i);
```

or

```
delete layout->takeAt(i);
```

In fact, is there any real difference between these last two?
I am assuming all my objects are on the heap of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is definitely no need to set widget's parent to `NULL` before deleting it. Child widget will automatically unregister from its parent upon deletion.

For your second question, real difference between `itemAt` and `takeAt` is that `itemAt` returns the specified layout item, `takeAt` returns it too but additionaly removes it from the layout.

Using `takeAt` changes the layout item count because it removed the returned item from the layout. So be careful, don't use it in a loop like `for ( int i = 0; i != layout->count(); ++i )` because you'll end up with i being greater than current `layout->count()`...

Note that doing `delete layout->itemAt(i);` does not automatically remove the deleted item from the layout, so this must be avoided.

Comment: Excellent, that confirms what I was thinking.
I'll avoid the delete layout->itemAt(i) if it cannot be trusted with testing. Thanks!