# Do I need to setParent to nullptr before deleting QWidget that's owned by QStackedWidget

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qstackedwidget

I have a QStackedWidget which has a bunch of static "pages" but in a couple of cases one page needs to be recreated when it's switched to. Currently I have something like this:

```
void InsetNavigator::Navigate(InsetPage *page)
{
    auto current_page = qobject_cast<InsetPage*>(stacked_widget_->currentWidget());
    auto current_idx = stacked_widget_->currentIndex();
    current_page->MadeHidden();
    stacked_widget_->removeWidget(current_page);
    current_page->setParent(nullptr);
    delete current_page;
    stacked_widget_->insertWidget(current_idx -1, page);
    stacked_widget_->setCurrentWidget(page);
    page->MadeVisible();
}
```

My question is, do I need to bother with reparenting the current page to a nullptr before deleting it, or can I just delete the current_page and the QStackedWidget will handle the fact that it's been deleted for me? I don't know if leaving the stacked widget as the parent but deleting the pointer will cause issues.

Comment: You have to call `removeWidget` and `delete currentPage` but you avoid to call `setParent`

Comment: ***Do I need to setParent to nullptr before deleting QWidget that's owned by QStackedWidget*** No, never. The destructor of QObject will notify the parent.

Comment: I did not post an answer because I expect there is a duplicate. Also I was hoping to find this information in the documentation but I did not.

Comment: there's a lot of stuff I hope to find in the documentation, but alas it's not :). I found similar sorts of questions but nothing explicitly stating what you just mentioned.

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817169/qt-qwidget-removal-and-deletion-setparentnull-necessary ? The only difference I can see is that the previous question is more general. There's also a quote from [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html): "You can also delete child objects yourself, and they will remove themselves from their parents," thus if there's any issue with _just delete_ -- file a bug!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the **container**-widget is implemented.

But in most-cases if not all, the container-widget (`QStackedWidget` in OP's case) updates own internal-state automatically once any child-widget is deleted.